# What different things can I do to keep my dogs teeth clean?

Tags: dogs, dental-care

One of my dogs has a "dirtier" mouth than my others. He hates me brushing his teeth. I'll keep doing that anyway, but what other things have you tried that have helped keep your dog's teeth clean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What bad breath solutions exist for dogs?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/271/what-bad-breath-solutions-exist-for-dogs)

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Minties](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CB7ELB4) and they seemed okay. But I tried [Tropiclean](http://www.wag.com/dog/p/tropiclean-fresh-breath-water-additive-16-oz-103120) based on some recommendations and had good results with it. It's what got rid of the plaque buildup in my big cat. I've used the gel for brushing, but the water additive is nicer since you don't have to try and fight with them to brush their teeth, and as far as I can tell they don't mind the taste. My cats seem to even prefer the taste of water with it in. Either that or they're just curious about it each time I put some in. :)